# Nginx Kubernetes POD stays in ContainerCreating

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I was able to setup the Kubernetes Cluster on Centos7 with one master and two worker nodes, however when I try to deploy a pod with nginx, the state of the pod stays in ContainerRunning forever and doesn't seem to get out of it.

For pod network I am using the calico.
Can you please help me resolve this issue? for some reason I don't feel satisfied moving forward without resolving this issue, I tried to check forums etc, since the last two days and this is the last resort that I am reaching out to you.

```
[root@kube-master ~]# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
[get pods result][1]
```

However when I run describe pods I see the below error for the nginx container under events section.

```
Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  41s (x8 over 11m)     kubelet,
kube-worker1  (combined from similar events): Failed to create pod
sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox
container
"ac77a42270009cba0c508e2fd82a84d6caef287bdb117d288d5193960b52abcb"
network for pod "nginx-6db489d4b7-2r4d2": networkPlugin cni failed to
set up pod "nginx-6db489d4b7-2r4d2_default" network: unable to connect
to Cilium daemon: failed to create cilium agent client after 30.000000
seconds timeout: Get http:///var/run/cilium/cilium.sock/v1/config:
dial unix /var/run/cilium/cilium.sock: connect: no such file or
directory
```

Hope you can help here.

**Edit 1:**

The ip address of the master VM is `192.168.40.133`

Used the below command to initialize the kubeadm:
`kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address 192.168.40.133`

Used the below command to install the pod network:
`kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.11/manifests/calico.yaml`

The `kubeadm init` above gave me the join command that I used to join the workers into the cluster.

All the VMs are connected to host and bridged network adapters.

Comment: In your question you mention that you are `using the calico` .. from error log we can see the error is from `unable to connect
to Cilium daemon` .. so can you share more details how you achieved it as i understand `You can install only one Pod network per cluster` .. so is it typo or share more details on your setup.

Comment: way more details needed: at least how did you create the cluster? with `kubeadm`? other?

Comment: I am using calico for the pod network, not sure why the nginx is expecting cilium.

Comment: @morgwai I issued the following command for kubeadm initialization. kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address 192.168.40.133

Comment: I wrote "way more", so please explain all details **in** **the** **question** not in a comment: how did you install calico, how did you join nodes, what is the subnet that virtual machines that you are using as your nodes are in, what is the IP of the virtual machine on which you created the master...

Comment: @morgwai I added the necessary details to the original question.

Comment: I'm guessing that all the other VMs that you joined as worker nodes are in 192.168.40.0/24 network, right? please confirm in the question :)

Answer (score 2):

your pod subnet (specified by `--pod-network-cidr`) clashes with the network your VMs are located in: these 2 have to be distinct. Use something else for the pod subnet, for example `10.244.0.0/16` and then edit calico.yaml before applying it as described in [the official docs](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/calico#installing-with-the-kubernetes-api-datastore50-nodes-or-less):

```
POD_CIDR="10.244.0.0/16"
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=${POD_CIDR} --apiserver-advertise-address 192.168.40.133
curl https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml -O
sed -i -e "s?192.168.0.0/16?${POD_CIDR}?g" calico.yaml
kubectl apply -f calico.yaml
```

hope this helps :)

note: you don't really need to specify `--apiserver-advertise-address` flag: `kubeadm` will detect correctly the main IP of the machine most of the time.

Comment: in the previous version of explanation of why `--apiserver-advertise-address` is not needed I gave a wrong example of necessary  usage: I mistook it with `--control-plane-endpoint`. fixed now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try this, but do I need to do a kubeadm reset before performing this ?

Comment: yes, definitely. Moreover, you need to reset all the iptables/ipvs as described in [the doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#tear-down). Personally, whenever I need to change something in the config of a test cluster, I usually just wipe the whole VM and set it up from scratch (reinstall OS that is), just in case ;] it takes just 2 minutes in the end: worthy investment against countless hours wasted because of some tiny bit that didn't get reset properly: just nuke it from the orbit ;)